# Getting Fatal Error when trying to run the Doctrine CLI on mac

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've been following the Doctrine getting-started docs and am immediately running into a problem with Doctrine's CLI.

If I try to run

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`

or

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:drop`

or even

`php /vendor/bin/doctrine`

I get this error in my terminal...

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry' not found in
>   /Users/admin/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/doctrine2-tutorial/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php:152

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Need more 'up to' info, may as well compare your code to the completed tutorial: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2-orm-tutorial

Comment: I have a cli-config.php file and a bootstrap.php file. I'm at 'Starting With a Product Entity' in the Getting Started guide. I've made an entity and am now attempting to update the database schema with...

`vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`

That's when I realised something was wrong and got the above error. I've since found that I get the same error no matter what I try to do with the CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a database use the following:

bin/console doctrine:database:create

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your database with doctrine, you may update your composer version with dependency, after you delete de composer.lock before taping this following commande :  **composer install**

Actually, the latest stable version of doctrine is **2.11.*** . To resolve this problem, i juste upadate my doctrine  :

```
{
    {
    "require": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.11.0",
    },
}
```

->vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create